# Matlab: iterating over a vector to give taylor expansion for each element

Tags: matlab, loops, iteration

I'm attempting to iterate over a vector `y`, using 2 nested `for` loops, to return a list of the sum of the taylor expansion for each number in the vector.

It keeps returning the error

> In an assignment A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.

Code:

```
n = 6 
y = zeros(1,n);
x = [0.785398,0.392699,0.19635,0.098175];

for i = (1:4)

    for i = 0:n

        y(i+1) = (-1).^i*x.^(2*i+1)/factorial(2*i+1); 

    end;

    SINx = sum(y)

end
```

Comment: You are using the same variable `i` for both inner and outer loops. Is that a typo?.

Comment: I really don't get anything of what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to fill y with a number a place n+1 while y only is of length n.

in other words:
`length(y) = 6` and you try to fill `y(6+1)`

also please try to avoid making 2 loop with the same counter so consider chancing the second loop counter with a `j`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say that this gives the Taylor expansion at each point, but it corrects your code

```
n = 6 
x = [0.785398, 0.392699, 0.19635, 0.098175];
y = zeros(n, size(x,2));

for j = 1:size(x,2)

    for i = 0:n-1

        y(i+1, :) = ((-1)^i) * x.^(2*i+1) ./ factorial(2*i+1); 

    end

    SINx = sum(y(i+1, :))

end
```